# Edit - Update Json File Online

Tags: php, ajax, json, jsonp

I would like to Edit my test.json File Online but i don't know how to start.
Output works good but I want to Update some Informations when i'am on
Holiday. I would like an Html Form to Submit new Data to the File.
Please help me to find this Solution....

> jsonTestfile(
>
> ```
> [{
>   "id":"1",
>   "date":"12.25.2013",
>   "time":"10.30 - 18.00 Uhr",
>   "description":"day of the tentacle",
>   "email":"email@test.json",
>   "special":"free for all",
>   "image":["json.png"]
> ```
>
> }
>   ]
>
> );

Best Regards

Masterluke